# How to update Pretext in Bokeh with a Select tool

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, bokeh

I have a bokeh plot that updates my plot through a select tool. The select tool contains subjects that update the plot where the values are `x='Polarity'`and `y='Subjectivity'`.

Here is a dummy data for what I want:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

list_type = ['All', 'Compliment', 'Sport', 'Remaining', 'Finance', 'Infrastructure', 'Complaint', 'Authority',
 'Danger', 'Health', 'English']



df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'Subject' : [list_type[i] for t in range(110)], 
                   'Polarity' : [random.random() for t in range(110)],
                   'Subjectivity' : [random.random() for t in range(110)]}) for i in range(len(list_type))], axis=0)
```

My code for updating the plot looks like this:

```
options = []
options.append('All')

options.extend(df['Subject'].unique().tolist())
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

p = figure()
r = p.circle(x='Polarity', y='Subjectivity', source = source)

select = Select(title="Subject",  options=options, value="All")
output_notebook()

def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    if select.value=="All":
        df_filter = df.copy()
    else:
        df_filter = df[df['Subject']==select.value]
    source1 = ColumnDataSource(df_filter)
    r.data_source.data = source1.data
select.on_change('value', update_plot)
layout = column(row(select, width=400), p)
#show(layout)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

I want to add a 'Pretext' that has a `df.describe()`, that can update with the plot through the select tool. I tried this by adding these codes but it displays nothing:

```
stats = PreText(text='', width=500)
t1 = select.value

def update_stats(df, t1):
    stats.text = str(df[[t1, select.value+'_returns']].describe())


select.on_change('value', update_plot, update_stats)
layout = column(row(select, width=400), p, stats)
curdoc().add_root(layout)

show(layout)
```

Anyone know a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two separate function for that, you can just change your original function `update_plot` to add statement to change the text for `PreText` as `stats.text = str(df_filter.describe())`. The function will look as below -

```
def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    if select.value=="All":
        df_filter = df.copy()
    else:
        df_filter = df[df['Subject']==select.value]
    source1 = ColumnDataSource(df_filter)
    r.data_source.data = source1.data
    stats.text = str(df_filter.describe())
```

**Entire code**

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select, PreText
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
import pandas as pd
import random


list_type = ['All', 'Compliment', 'Sport', 'Remaining', 'Finance', 'Infrastructure', 'Complaint', 'Authority',
 'Danger', 'Health', 'English']



df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'Subject' : [list_type[i] for t in range(110)], 
                   'Polarity' : [random.random() for t in range(110)],
                   'Subjectivity' : [random.random() for t in range(110)]}) for i in range(len(list_type))], axis=0)

options = []
options.append('All')

options.extend(df['Subject'].unique().tolist())
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

p = figure()
r = p.circle(x='Polarity', y='Subjectivity', source = source)

select = Select(title="Subject",  options=options, value="All")
#output_notebook()

stats = PreText(text=str(df.describe()), width=500)

def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    if select.value=="All":
        df_filter = df.copy()
    else:
        df_filter = df[df['Subject']==select.value]
    source1 = ColumnDataSource(df_filter)
    r.data_source.data = source1.data
    stats.text = str(df_filter.describe())


select.on_change('value', update_plot)
layout = column(row(select, width=400), p, stats)
#show(layout)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Comment: Very good and easy solution! Thank you very much. I should have seen this myself.

Comment: @Aritesh : I am witnessing a rather off situation where the PreText text isnt updating on each callback. Any idea why that would happen ?
It does update on most of the occassion, but for some it seems to just get stuck.
is it requiring some clearing ?

Comment: @asimo Can you please provide some code/instance this is happening?